# Wordpress get all categories associated with post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I've created a custom post type with taxonomies and have a template page to display the cpt. Is it possible to get all the categories attached to a post within the loop and output them on the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that

```
foreach ( get_posts( 'numberposts=-1') as $post ) {
     wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'category_name', 'category');
}
```

Comment: can this be inside the loop?